# How would liquibase work for different deployments or prod environments on integration with maven plugin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, liquibase, jooq

I have integrated **liquibase with maven plugin** (in pom.xml) along with **jOOQ generator** that reads from db connection after liquibase migration.
The liquibase migration -> jooq generator runs on running **mvn clean compile** (Compile and build step).
I am wondering how will the liquibase change-management work for different deployments or **different prod environments**?
Will it **create tables automatically** for all the prod environments? Please guide.

Comment: Is this really a different question from your previous one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71552585/521799

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the same ask as your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71552585/521799).

If it's not the same, then the first place to look is [Liquibase Documentation for Maven](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/home.html) and then the jOOQ manual for [Code generation from Liquibase XML, YAML, JSON files](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-liquibase/).